# problem with camera info

Tags: ros, camera-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

I tried to load my camera info from one yaml that I created with camera calibrate.
I wrote this code:

```
if (info_manager_->validateURL("$(find camera)/webcam.yaml"))
  {
      ROS_INFO("sucsses");
  }
  else
  {
      ROS_ERROR("NEGETIVE");
  }
```

but I couldn't access the yaml and I got negetive msg and  this is my yaml:

```
image_width: 640
image_height: 480
camera_name: webcam
camera_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [628.605769204058, 0, 330.525636957696, 0, 626.873332341329, 252.463246920169, 0, 0, 1]
distortion_model: plumb_bob
distortion_coefficients:
  rows: 1
  cols: 5
  data: [-0.0709132085265088, 0.102063002021842, -0.00113116095948083, -3.15823206599607e-05, 0]
rectification_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
projection_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 4
  data: [620.937438964844, 0, 329.896849376601, 0, 0, 620.437438964844, 251.769990192599, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182399/problem-with-camera-info/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure how this "info_manager_->validateURL" function works but I don't think that "$(find camera)/webcam.yaml" as path will work, you are using C++ and $(find camera) will not be automatically replaced by the package's path like in CMakeFiles. You could first try to put the full path to your yaml file

> for example :
> /home/yourusername/workspace/camera/webcam.yaml

depending on where your package is installed. If that works then just put "webcam.yaml" and run your node from the package's folder.

```
roscd camera  and then rosrun
```

If you want to be able to run your node from anywhere without having to put the full path to the yaml file check this answer:
http://answers.ros.org/question/173970/how-to-load-a-file-contained-in-a-package/#179206

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-07-05**:
I tried with this "~/Working_space/camera/calibrate/webcam.yaml" but I got negetive msg :( . I want to do some thing such as cv_camera in this link https://github.com/OTL/cv_camera/blob/master/src/capture.cpp
in 54 line.